# Failed to persist etcd/raft data: input/output error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, etcd, raft

I'm running a Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.1 using etcd/raft and I'm running on this error on the orderers of the network whenever I send a transaction to the orderer.

We have observed this 12 times in a period of 9 days.

What might be the causes of it?

```
2019-08-07 17:06:07.241 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] 2 -> DEBU 7fc91 Proposed block [15] to raft consensus channel=pocccssinciensaled node=2
2019-08-07 17:06:07.242 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] run -> PANI 7fc92 Failed to persist etcd/raft data: input/output error channel=pocccssinciensaled node=2
panic: Failed to persist etcd/raft data: input/output error

goroutine 68 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore.(*CheckedEntry).Write(0xc0000ede40, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore/entry.go:229 +0x515
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).log(0xc00000e258, 0x104, 0x1033fcb, 0x24, 0xc0002f9bc8, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:234 +0xf6
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).Panicf(0xc00000e258, 0x1033fcb, 0x24, 0xc0002f9bc8, 0x1, 0x1)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:159 +0x79
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging.(*FabricLogger).Panicf(0xc00000e260, 0x1033fcb, 0x24, 0xc0002f9bc8, 0x1, 0x1)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging/zap.go:74 +0x60
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/consensus/etcdraft.(*node).run(0xc000586500, 0x0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/consensus/etcdraft/node.go:118 +0x43c
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/consensus/etcdraft.(*node).start
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/consensus/etcdraft/node.go:80 +0x218
```

Comment: Try using Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.2 for using etcd/raft its much more stable for supporting raft consensus. I also ran into errors then I have shifted on 1.4.2 and now its working fine till now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Trinayan, I'm currently using 1.4.1 and in the changelog for 1.4.2 I don't see anything about stability for raft. Do you still think it's worth changing it to 1.4.2 or 1.4.1 would be fine?

Comment: As far as my experience with raft till now in version 1.4.2 I am very much satisfied with the raft consensus protocol and haven't faced any problem. There are some definite advancements made in 1.4.2 related to raft consensus so its not a bad option to migrate to the new version.